# how to work on soap and wsdl on iphone

Tags: iphone

Can any one give example how to work with soap[Simple Object Access Protocol] and wsdl      [Web Services Description Language] for iphone......

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://sudzc.com/Tutorial/ObjC.mov

Hoping it will help.